# Copy List with Random Pointer. What is the second while loop doing here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, hashmap

```py
"""
# Definition for a Node.
class Node:
    def __init__(self, x: int, next: 'Node' = None, random: 'Node' = None):
        self.val = int(x)
        self.next = next
        self.random = random
"""

class Solution:
    def copyRandomList(self, head: 'Node') -> 'Node':
        oldToCopy = { None : None} 
        
        curr = head 
        while curr:
            copy = Node(curr.val)
            oldToCopy[curr] = copy 
            curr = curr.next 
            
        curr = head 
        while curr:
            copy = oldToCopy[curr]
            copy.next = oldToCopy[curr.next]
            copy.random = oldToCopy[curr.random]
            curr = curr.next 
            
        return oldToCopy[head]
```

This code is making a Deep Copy of a linked list. In the first while loop, we make a copy of each node value and put it in the hashmap. In the second while loop, we set `copy` as the values obtained from the hashmap?

How does assigning `copy`, `copy.next` and `copy.random` to values from the hashmap return an answer when I do `oldToCopy[head]`.

Confused as to what this code is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help to visiualise the process with an example:

```
 head          ┌──────────────────────┐
  ↓            │                      v
┌─────────────┐│  ┌─────────────┐   ┌─────────────┐
│ val: 1      ││  │ val: 2      │   │ val: 3      │
│ next: ───────│─>│ next: ─────────>│ next:None   │
│ random: ─────┘  │ random: None│<─────── :random │
└─────────────┘   └─────────────┘   └─────────────┘
```

So this example is a linked list with 3 nodes. The first has a `random` reference to  the last node. And the last node has a `random` reference to the middle node. The middle node has no `random` reference (it is `None`).

This is the result after the first loop has completed:

```
 head          ┌──────────────────────┐
  ↓            │                      v
┌─────────────┐│  ┌─────────────┐   ┌─────────────┐
│ val: 1      ││  │ val: 2      │   │ val: 3      │
│ next: ───────│─>│ next: ─────────>│ next: None  │
│ random: ─────┘  │ random: None│<─────── :random │
└─────────────┘   └─────────────┘   └─────────────┘
   oldToCopy         oldToCopy         oldToCopy
       │                 │                 │
       │                 │                 │
       v                 v                 v
┌─────────────┐   ┌─────────────┐   ┌─────────────┐
│ val: 1      │   │ val: 2      │   │ val: 3      │
│ next: None  │   │ next: None  │   │ next: None  │
│ random: None│   │ random: None│   │ random: None│
└─────────────┘   └─────────────┘   └─────────────┘
```

Some explanation of the above diagram which now has lots of references:

- The bottom three nodes are the new nodes created with `new Node()`.
- The references in those new nodes (i.e. their `next` and `random` attributes) are all `None`, because we didn't (and couldn't yet) pass any good values for those attributes. The new nodes only have their `val` attribute set correctly.
- `oldToCopy` is a dictionary keyed by the old nodes. Given an old node, it gives the corresponding new node. So this is also depicted with a downwards arrow.

Now let's go through the second loop -- step by step.

First `curr` and `copy` are defined as follows:

```
 curr
 head          ┌──────────────────────┐
  ↓            │                      v
┌─────────────┐│  ┌─────────────┐   ┌─────────────┐
│ val: 1      ││  │ val: 2      │   │ val: 3      │
│ next: ───────│─>│ next: ─────────>│ next: None  │
│ random: ─────┘  │ random: None│<─────── :random │
└─────────────┘   └─────────────┘   └─────────────┘
   oldToCopy         oldToCopy         oldToCopy
       │                 │                 │
       │                 │                 │
       v                 v                 v
┌─────────────┐   ┌─────────────┐   ┌─────────────┐
│ val: 1      │   │ val: 2      │   │ val: 3      │
│ next: None  │   │ next: None  │   │ next: None  │
│ random: None│   │ random: None│   │ random: None│
└─────────────┘   └─────────────┘   └─────────────┘
  ↑
 copy
```

Then we execute `copy.next = oldToCopy[curr.next]`. We note that `curr.next` is the middle old node. `oldToCopy[curr.next]` is the node right below it (new node). And so `copy.next = oldToCopy[curr.next]` has this effect on the `next` attribute of the first new node:

```
 curr
 head          ┌──────────────────────┐
  ↓            │                      v
┌─────────────┐│  ┌─────────────┐   ┌─────────────┐
│ val: 1      ││  │ val: 2      │   │ val: 3      │
│ next: ───────│─>│ next: ─────────>│ next: None  │
│ random: ─────┘  │ random: None│<─────── :random │
└─────────────┘   └─────────────┘   └─────────────┘
   oldToCopy         oldToCopy         oldToCopy
       │                 │                 │
       │                 │                 │
       v                 v                 v
┌─────────────┐   ┌─────────────┐   ┌─────────────┐
│ val: 1      │   │ val: 2      │   │ val: 3      │
│ next: ─────────>│ next: None  │   │ next: None  │
│ random: None│   │ random: None│   │ random: None│
└─────────────┘   └─────────────┘   └─────────────┘
  ↑
 copy
```

A similar thing happens when we execute `copy.random = oldToCopy[curr.random]`. `curr.random` is the last old node. And `oldToCopy[curr.random]` is the node right below it. And so `copy.random = oldToCopy[curr.random]` has this effect on the `random` attribute of the first new node:

```
 curr
 head          ┌──────────────────────┐
  ↓            │                      v
┌─────────────┐│  ┌─────────────┐   ┌─────────────┐
│ val: 1      ││  │ val: 2      │   │ val: 3      │
│ next: ───────│─>│ next: ─────────>│ next: None  │
│ random: ─────┘  │ random: None│<─────── :random │
└─────────────┘   └─────────────┘   └─────────────┘
   oldToCopy         oldToCopy         oldToCopy
       │                 │                 │
       │                 │                 │
       v                 v                 v
┌─────────────┐   ┌─────────────┐   ┌─────────────┐
│ val: 1      │   │ val: 2      │   │ val: 3      │
│ next: ─────────>│ next: None  │   │ next: None  │
│ random: ───────┐│ random: None│   │ random: None│
└─────────────┘  │└─────────────┘   └─────────────┘
  ↑              │                   ^
 copy            └───────────────────┘
```

The first iteration of the loop completes by moving the `curr` reference to the next node in the original list. This iteration made the `next` and `random` attributes of the first, new node to reference new nodes instead of old nodes.

The next iteration will do the same with the second new node -- where `random` was and remains `None`, but `next` will be rewired -- and so we get:

```
               ┌──────────────────────┐
 head          │   curr               │
  ↓            │    ↓                 v
┌─────────────┐│  ┌─────────────┐   ┌─────────────┐
│ val: 1      ││  │ val: 2      │   │ val: 3      │
│ next: ───────│─>│ next: ─────────>│ next: None  │
│ random: ─────┘  │ random: None│<─────── :random │
└─────────────┘   └─────────────┘   └─────────────┘
   oldToCopy         oldToCopy         oldToCopy
       │                 │                 │
       │                 │                 │
       v                 v                 v
┌─────────────┐   ┌─────────────┐   ┌─────────────┐
│ val: 1      │   │ val: 2      │   │ val: 3      │
│ next: ────────> │ next: ─────────>│ next: None  │
│ random: ───────┐│ random: None│   │ random: None│
└─────────────┘  │└─────────────┘   └─────────────┘
                 │  ↑                 ^
                 │ copy               │
                 └────────────────────┘
```

The last iteration will do the same with the last new node:

```
 head          ┌──────────────────────┐  curr
  ↓            │                      v   ↓
┌─────────────┐│  ┌─────────────┐   ┌─────────────┐
│ val: 1      ││  │ val: 2      │   │ val: 3      │
│ next: ───────│─>│ next: ─────────>│ next: None  │
│ random: ─────┘  │ random: None│<─────── :random │
└─────────────┘   └─────────────┘   └─────────────┘
   oldToCopy         oldToCopy         oldToCopy
       │                 │                 │
       │                 │                 │
       v                 v                 v
┌─────────────┐   ┌─────────────┐   ┌─────────────┐
│ val: 1      │   │ val: 2      │   │ val: 3      │
│ next: ────────> │ next: ─────────>│ next: None  │
│ random: ───────┐│ random: None│<─────── :random │
└─────────────┘  │└─────────────┘   └─────────────┘
                 │                    ^    ↑
                 └────────────────────┘   copy
```

Finally, the function returns `oldToCopy[head]`, which is the reference to the cloned list, which now has no more references to old nodes.

Comment: I get that in the first loop we have a hashmap, 'oldToCopy', and we assign a key 'curr' and a value 'copy'. In the second loop, how is it that assigning 'copy = oldToCopy[curr]' makes any changes to the linked list? 

I could be misunderstanding linked list using hashmap (it's very confusing for me), but from your explanation, I believe making modification to a 'node.val' by setting it as 'copy' then assigning a value for 'copy.next' changes the entire node itself. I think I'm getting it~

Comment: `copy = oldToCopy[curr]` does not make any changes to the linked list. It merely asks from the dictionary to give the new node reference when we know the old node reference. So that dictionary provides the downward arrows depicted in the diagram: you give it an original node, and it hands you the new node that was created for it. Just take your time to go through the diagrams, and don't move to the next until you fully understand how a diagram follows from one piece of code.

Comment: I went through the diagrams multiple times and I finally understand now. Great explanation.

Answer (score 2):

It's a linked list, so each node has a pointer to the next node (and in this case also a pointer to a random node).

The first loop constructs `oldToCopy`, which is a map of original node to node copy. This means that when you look something up in `oldToCopy` you're using the original node as a key to retrieve the copy of that node.

The second loop then iterates over the original list again and:

- `copy` is assigned to point to the copy of the node `curr` that was made in the first loop (this is just for convenience to avoid using `oldToCopy[curr]` over and over again).
- `copy.next` is assigned to point to the *copy* of the node that `curr.next` points to.
- `copy.random` is assigned similarly.

Setting the `next` and `random` pointers for each copy is done in two loops because when you're copying node `x` you don't yet have a copy of the node pointed to by `x.next` - you'll be making that copy in the next iteration.

Comment: I'm confused, what does assigning values for copy, copy.next, and copy.random do here?

Comment: It's a linked list, so each node has a pointer to the next node (and in this case also a pointer to a random node it seems). When you look something up in `oldToCopy` you're using the original node as a key to retrieve the copy of that node. Following the lines, `copy` is assigned to point to the newly created copy of the node (this is just for convenience to avoid using `oldToCopy[curr]` over and over again), `copy.next` is assigned to point to the *copy* of the node that `curr.next` points to, and `copy.random` is assigned similarly.

Answer (score 1):

First Loop **just creates new nodes** with existing node's values. (**No references are assigned here.**)

*Say a node - `node1` has val=5, next=`node2` and random=`node4`*

```
oldToCopy = {node1: new_node1}
```

Second Loop assigns the references (`next` and `random`) to the newly created nodes.

*Since the `node1`s, next=`node2` and random=`node4`, the newly created `new_node1` should also have the same references **but they must point to newly created nodes - `new_node2` and `new_node4`. and not the old ones(`node2` and `node4`).***

That is what this code does for every newly created node.

```
# Gets the new node/copy of curr node from dict
copy = oldToCopy[curr]
# set the next pointer 
copy.next = oldToCopy[curr.next]
# set the random pointer
copy.random = oldToCopy[curr.random]
# move to the next node
curr = curr.next
```

Comment: How does setting copy, copy.next, copy.random equal to value of curr, curr.next and curr.random respectively from the hashmap do anything to the hashmap itself? In the end, oldToCopy[head] is returned but the hashmap itself hasn't been touched.